# How can I make C8 output total code coverage %?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage, chai, nyc

I am able to generate code coverage reports using c8.
[image]

But how do I output total coverage % every time? Currently, it outputs total coverage % only if it is less than the threshold like this.
[image]

But I wanted to see the % every time it runs.

Config :

```
{
  "include": "app",
  "check-coverage": true,
  "lines": 99,
  "reporter": ["text","cobertura"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to add "text-summary" as one of the reporters.

```
"reporter": ["text","text-summary","cobertura"]
```